# Connecting a P2S VPN to a VNET

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a P2S VPN to connect to an Azure subscription that contains several servers I want to access. Connecting from my private Notebook to this P2S VPN works perfectly.

In addition I have my own Azure subscription containing several virtual machines. Now I can setup the P2S VPN Client on each of these. However, this does not seem to be an elegant solution. I'd like to just create one VNET and connect this VNET to my existing P2SVPN. Then I could connect all my virtual machines to that VNET and would be very happy.

How can this be done? All my research just shows how to connect a client to the P2S VPN. Other pages show how I can connect to one VNET and setup a S2S VPN to another VNET.

Thanks

Comment: Are all machines in the same tenant? When you login to 'the portal' can you see all machines?

Comment: No the systems are located in totally different regions with totally different administrators in no shared subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a hub-spoke topology in Azure. The topology like this:

[image]

You can connect your VMs in different Vnet just through only one Vnet. And this topology overcomes subscriptions limits by peering VNets from different subscriptions to the central hub. For more details, see [Implement a hub-spoke network topology in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke). Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since VMs (subscriptions) are not in the same Tenant, it will be easier to just have a P2S connection for each.

Peering will not work, but you can setup S2S for both VNet but that is not a feasible solution.

Comment: How can I do S2S when I have no influence on the subscription / VNET / everything where the servers that I want to access reside?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by no influence.  Any solution you come up with will need you to have access or have contact with someone that has access to both VNets. What is meant in my answer is P2S for each VNet from you NoteBook and you can access all machines in both VNet.

Comment: I have a working P2S connection to the second VNet (i.e. i have the downloadable VPN client to access that VNet). Everything I want to do is to reshare that connection so that I do not have to setup this client on all my machines.